# InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast : Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having issues getting a stream of a document. When casting `documentSnapshot.data() as DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` I get the error:
`_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast`

I'm using bloc; the StreamSubscription is created in the bloc like this:

```
  on<FetchContacts>((event, emit) async {
  try {
    emit(FetchingContacts().copyWith(
        username: state.username,
        status: Formz.validate([state.username])));

    subscription = userDataRepository.getContacts().listen((contacts) =>
        {print('adding $contacts'), add(ReceiveContacts(contacts))});
```

And the contacts stream is created in the repository like this (truncated):

```
Stream<List<Contact>> getContacts() {

final contactsStream = userRef.snapshots().transform(StreamTransformer<
        DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>, List<Contact>>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (documentSnapshot, sink) =>
        mapDocumentToContact(usersRef, userRef, documentSnapshot, sink)));
}

Future<void> mapDocumentToContact(etc)

final data =
    documentSnapshot.data()! as DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>;
```

The error is thrown at `final data = ...`

This is the structure of the Firestore db (the document I'm trying to subscribe to is a user):

[image: Firestore structure]

Any help is appreciated, I've seen questions being asked about a similar error that were resolved using `Map<String, dynamic>>.from(snapshot.data())` instead of `as Map<String, dynamic>>` but unfortunately I can't do this with `DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>`

Comment: Are you trying to listen user doc changes? You might need to use ```StreamSubscription```

Comment: Have you tried using `StreamBuilder` ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that I create the subscription in the bloc, updated question to reflect this.

Comment: Did you try using `fromJson()` instead of `from()` ?

Comment: DocumentSnapshot doesn't have from() or fromJson() defined but I managed to figure it out, answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Turns out I don't have to use `DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>`, at what works is in fact (similarly to the other questions I found): `final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(documentSnapshot.data()!);`